# CodeIgniter 3: Function assignment by reference

Tags: php, error-handling, runtime-error, codeigniter-3

I have a CodeIgniter 3 application **that cannot be converted to CI4 or anything else for that matter** given that it is a large application of over 2 million lines of code, is a business critical system, andthere is no budget or time to do this right now. I therefore need a solution other than instead of "Upgrade your platform" or "Use a different platform", please :-)

Here is the problem:

In CodeIgniter 3, the function `get_instance()` is declared by reference:

```
function &get_instance()
{
    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

We are getting this error on PHP 8.0.27 (it is not our production server - that is on PHP 8.1, we're trying to test the waters on a test server before going to 8.2 on production):

```
Notice: Only variables should be assigned by reference in 
--------/views/errors/html/error_php.php on line 80
```

Some part of our code is broken, and our error handler is triggered, which bombs out in this case (original error is not shown - only the error that occurs in the error handler). Our error handler is obviously borked, which I am trying to resolve. It appears at the time this error occurs that the CI super object seems to be not available.

Solving the error that triggers the error handler would make this go away for this particular case, but is not a solution, because the next error that occurs will just bring it back, so hopefully someone has a solution to the fact that CI uses `function &get_isntance()` declaration which our PHP version does not like, preferably in such a way that I do not have to retrofit an entire 2 million line codebase (right now).

Comment: "_that has tens of thousands of users_" How is that a criteria for not upgrading your platform? What if there is no other solution but to "_Upgrade your platform_"?

Comment: You may not agree with my reasons for not being able to upgrade now. The fact is, I cannot upgrade. Does not mean I do not want to, or will make incremental upgrades over time, but CI4 is not backward compatible with CI3, and rewriting the entire system is not in client's budget or timeframe RIGHT NOW. I do not know what the future hold, but your comment is not helpful. I did edit the post a bit to prevent more comments like this.

Comment: I just didn't agree with you stating that the number of users on a platform is a criteria for not upgrading the platform. Client budget is a different thing. (That _error_ is a _notice_ btw) Good luck

Comment: I'm also stuck with CI3 on a particular 100K LOC app. Upgrading PHP version is an issue. I had to patch many things in CI3. Why not just remove `&`? It's an artifact from before PHP 5.

Comment: @akinuri - is it as simple as just removing the `&` in the definition `function &get_instance()` as well as everywhere where I use something like `$ci =& get_instance()`? Would that actually work just like that? Would it not create new copies of the super object all the time?

Comment: Your situation seems very unusual. It might not be about the definiton. I see that the error file is modified ("error_php.php on line 80"), as it's normally 30~ lines. If this file is the cause of the issue, the fix should be applied in there. What is there at line 80? ... I haven't encountered this issue myself, and I haven't modified the `get_instance()` function. It might also be specific to the PHP version `8.0.27`.

Comment: It sounds like you might have the time to update the code later - up till then you could just disable the output of PHP notices to buy you some time. A notice shouldn't be critical - of course it's always good to fix even them if possible and when possible.

Comment: @akinuri - yes, we have a custom error handler. The problem was quite strange and had many points of impact. First, we recently had a CSRF implementation and the form is posting from outside, but was not excluded from the CSRF, this (for some reason I have not investigated yet, the CI super object to be not available, but once I excluded the external post from CSRF, I could see the actual error, which was in another part of the code, and fixed it. Usually, the CI super object is available to our error handler, just not sure why not this time. Not sure it is optimal, but works now. Thanks!